# How can I change my OpenID?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts, login

Hello friends, I have my two OpenIDs connected to my Stack Overflow account.

One is Yahoo and other is **(Google profile)** I want to change this Google profile to Gmail login... (I am not able to understand the difference between Google profile and Gmail one).

#### My scenario

**Case 1:** I am logged in to Yahoo! Mail and I am able to log in at stackoverflow.com. (Perfect. No problem)

**Case 2:** I am logged in to Gmail or iGoogle or Orkut or Blogger. At that time **I am not able to log in** at stackoverflow.com. (MY original account. Username piemesons)

In order for me to log in at stackoverflow.com, I must use my google profile OpenID: `www.google.com/profiles/jain.mohit27`

Why this is happening? I am not able to understand: what's the difference between my Gmail id and Google id?

One other thing I tried:

1. Open a new browser. Log out of everything: Yahoo, Google, etc.
2. Now log in to Gmail.
3. Open stackoverflow.com and try to log in using Google.
4. Site asks me to created a new account. (A brand-new account - WHY?)
5. I try to swap OpenIds.
6. Enter `www.google.com/profiles/jain.mohit27` as my OpenID. I got my original account.
7. Now again swap OpenID, and try using Google. AND I GOT A NEW ACCOUNT - WHY IS THIS SO?

Can anybody explain this and tell me what to do?

Anybody..????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I correctly understand what's going on, but it seems as if you're unable to associate your Gmail login with your account. Here's how you do that:

1. Make sure you're logged in to Stack Overflow.
2. Go to your Profile, and, if your Yahoo OpenID is listed in the "openid" field (not "alt openid"), click swap. This will change your OpenIDs around so that your Google profile OpenID becomes the primary one.
3. Login to Gmail
4. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login while logged in to SO.
5. Click the Google icon above the OpenID input text box.
6. It will log you in with your Gmail OpenID, and will ask if you want to associate the OpenID with your current account. Answer yes. This will overwrite your Google profile OpenID with your Gmail OpenID on Stack Overflow.
7. Now, go to your profile page. You can see what two OpenIDs are registered with your account. Next time you have to log in, you can use either of them: you don't have to swap them first.

Hope I helped!

Comment: This is scary. You beat me by a few seconds, and the biggest difference between your and my answer is that I used a bullet list and not a numbered list :) +1

Comment: @balpha aww, I'm sorry... but thanks.

Comment: Not working dude.... i already tried that...